# syncing two maildirs

Tags: synchronization, email, maildir

I have a server that I use to frequently get email from Google using `offlineimap`. the email is stored in a maildir format on this server.

What tool can I use to sync this maildir with the local maildir that is on my latop?

I've tried `getmail` but that doesn't have a two-way sync. `syncmaildir` gave me headaches (kept crashing, plus has some strange dependencies on gtk). `rsync` seems too brutal.

I need a simple tool that can be used over ssh to get new emails from the server, update the flags (read, etc) and delete deleted messages.

What have you guys used so far? What are the perks of your proposed tools?

Comment: Why not rsync?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BenjaminBarenblat Not the OP, but for one, the files almost certainly don't have the same names. You'd need something that understands the concept of email messages for this, rather than simply files.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [isync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/isync/):

> A command line utility for synchronizing remote IMAP mailboxes and local maildir-style mailboxes. This is useful for working in disconnected (off-line) mode, such as on a laptop, but also for mirroring mailboxes between servers.

I have found it helpful to rebuild an IMAP remote cache from a local one after the server was *(cough)* accidentally deleted...

Answer (score 1):

What about `offlineimap` again? (running an imap server instance on the *server*).